# File zipped by java.util.zip can't be decompressed by standard zip utility

Tags: java, android, zip

I managed to create zip file in java using this simple piece of code:

```
BufferedInputStream origin = null;
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
out.setLevel(5);

byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
out.putNextEntry(entry);

int count;
while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
    out.write(data, 0, count);
}

out.closeEntry();
origin.close();
out.close();
```

zip file created successfully. However when I try to unzip it using WinZip or some other tools I get an error:

```
Central and local directory mismatch for file "my_file" (general 
purpose flags - local:808 hex  central: 8 hex). 
Severe Error:  Local and central GPFlags values don't match.
```

What's really weird, WinRAR and internal Win7 zip do not show any errors when I decompress the file.

What am I doing wrong? Anybody had this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Found related question, I also use java in Android 2.3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407695/android-2-3-zip-problems-with-general-purpose-flags

Answer (score 1):

Must be that out.close is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close zipentry.

```
out.closeEntry();
origin.close();
out.close();
```